# How to run Go exe file as service using kardinoas pkg

Tags: go

```
// Copyright 2015 Daniel Theophanes.
// Use of this source code is governed by a zlib-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

// simple does nothing except block while running the service.
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/kardianos/service"
)

var logger service.Logger

type program struct{}

func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
    go p.run()
    return nil
}
func (p *program) run() {
    // Do work here
     for range time.Tick(time.Second * 10)  {
        TomcatPort := strings.Split(TomcatPort,",")
        TomcatName := strings.Split(TomcatName,",")
        for i,port := range TomcatPort {
            go NeverStop(port,TomcatName[i])
            wg.Add(1)
        }
    wg.Wait()

}
func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
    return nil
}

func main() {
    svcConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
        DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
        Description: "This is an example Go service.",
    }

    prg := &program{}
    s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = s.Install()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
    err = s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
}
func NeverStop(port string,Name string){
defer wg.Done()
data := fmt.Sprintf("%v is %v",Name,pharse)
google_chat_check.StartingPoint(map[string]string{"data": data},ChatSpaceName)
}
```

*I'm gonna try this way but the service didn't create, If anyone help me out solve this problem would be appreciatable!!!*

---

steps I do:

1. Using kardianos pkg I'm using the sample folder they mention is Github
2. Then I add my code to Run method section
3. Here I'm using grouting as for loop.
4. My method will act as a thread
5. Even though I got a problem to create as a service

Comment: Unfortunately "I got a problem" is not really enough information for us to help. Please provide more info i.e. details of error (if any), what you did, what OS are you using, do you have administrative rights, did the [demo](https://github.com/kardianos/service/tree/master/example/simple) work etc.

Comment: I'm using windows so I have administrative rights, Generally, I want to know how to create a go exe file as a service using Kardinaos pkg, That's it I want? Do you know that can you just help me out?

Comment: "so I have administrative rights" by this do you mean that you are running your command from an "Administrator" command prompt (i.e. right click, run as administrator) - if not then that is probably the issue. I can't really help more without further details (an error message at a minimum).